# JOIN with multiple reference to the same table on the right

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables...

```
Table 1 (columns): user1 user2 user3 (each contain ids referencing to Table 2)

Table 2 (columns): id name phone email
```

I'm wanting to get the name/phone/email from Table 2 for all three users from one MySQL statement.

**Sample Data:**

Table 1

```
         User1   User2   User3
Row 1    4       2       5
Row 2    1       3       3
```

Table 2

```
         ID      Phone           Email
Row 1    1       777-940-2812    a@gmail.com
Row 2    2       483-329-4939    b@gmail.com
Row 3    3       849-393-9202    c@gmail.com
Row 4    4       920-282-2039    d@gmail.com
Row 5    5       102-203-4822    e@gmail.com
```

**Desired Outcome in one MySQL statement:**

```
       U1Phone      U1Email     U2Phone      U2Email     U3Phone      U3Email
Row 1  920-282-2039 d@gmail.com 483-329-4939 b@gmail.com 102-203-4822 e@gmail.com
Row 2  777-940-2812 a@gmail.com 849-393-9202 c@gmail.com 849-393-9202 c@gmail.com
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Done. Hope it makes it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Join the mapping table with users table three times using the user1 Id user2 Id and user3 I'd, one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` to `Table2` multiple times. Also, `Table1` should have a primary key of some sort. That would be what I assume you want to `ORDER BY`.

```sql
    SELECT u1.name as U1Name, u1.phone as U1Phone, u1.email as U1Email,
    u2.name as U2Name, u2.phone as U2Phone, u2.email as U2Email,
    u3.name as U3Name, u3.phone as U3Phone, u3.email as U3Email
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 u1 ON t1.User1 = u1.id
    LEFT JOIN Table2 u2 ON t1.User2 = u2.id
    LEFT JOIN Table2 u3 ON t1.User3 = u3.id
```

Comment: Worked! Comparing this simplified syntax to my original one, I discovered an error I made. Thanks for the reply and help.

Comment: @JustinTime. Great! (And thanks to Madhur Bhaiya for correcting my cut-and-paste typo). If this works, perhaps you can mark the answer "accepted".